# Change netbeans c99 comment style to //

Tags: c, button, comments, c99, netbeans-8

For Netbeans 8.1 using C (C99), the comment-out button uses `/*...*/` as it's default style.

However, this poses an issue when trying to comment out other comments, as the comment block will stop as soon as it comes across the first `*/`.   ie

```
/*
/* 
code here is commented
*/ 
this code is not commented
*/
```

Is there a way to switch the default style to `//` comments?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Another way to comment out code is by enclosing it with `#ifdef SOMETHING ... #endif`. Note that the coding standard MISRA forbids the use of `/* ... */` for commenting out code.

Comment: Alternatively just enclose between #if 0 ... #endif